# Regex for Affiliate URL

Tags: regex, matomo, piwiktracker

For Matomo outgoing link tracking I need the regex pattern, which matched the following URLs:
https://www.example.com/product/?sku=12345&utm_source=123456789

and

https://www.example.com/product/?utm_source=123456789

"https://www.example.com/" and "utm_source=123456789" are always fixed in the URL, just "product/" or "category/product/" change  and must replaced by regex pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you reach your goal:

```
(?<=https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/).+(?=utm_source=123456789)
```

It looks for any characters between these two groups:

- `https://www.example.com/`
- `utm_source=123456789`

Given the examples:

- `https://www.example.com/product/?sku=12345&utm_source=123456789`
- `https://www.example.com/product/?utm_source=123456789`

Your matches would be:

- `product/?sku=12345&`
- `product/?`